# System App - Extra privileges, Read Only file system permission

Tags: android, filesystems, wifi, android-file, android-permissions

I am trying to read **wpa_supplicant.conf** file on android system that stores saved wifi network details along with credentials.

The file is available and as a super user on a rooted device i can read file. But not on normal device as we don't have read permission.

So If i tie up with a mobile manufacturing company and ask them to bundle my app along with preinstalled app. Signing it up with the manufacturer signature. Will i get read permission to file system then? Or what should i precisely seek from the manufacturing team to get read only permissions. Or i am thinking in complete wrong direction. Please suggest.

What other permissions and privileges app get at different layer of android system. Say pre bundled or system app.

Comment: If you plan on releasing the app to the public, you'd need to sign up with EVERY device manufacturer.  And OEMs charge a lot of money to be bundled.  If you're an internal tool, you can just root the device and add it as a system app yourself by putting it in the right directory (it isn't about the signature, its about being in the system folder).

Comment: As for what system level permissions exist-  anything on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html marked "Not for use by third-party"

Comment: @Gabe Sechan . I am making a app to go public and can go with OEMs to bundle my app. As i mentioned, On rooted device i am able to read file.

Comment: I have also gone through with the list of permission. But i am confused which permission will give me read-only permission on file syetem